# Crear funciones para crear una ventana y cerrarla si se desea

Tags: javascript

La cuestión es que, en el libro de programación en Javascript desde donde estoy estudiando, aparece un ejemplo de un programa que crea una ventana con los parámetros que el usuario haya escogido, y la cierra si el usuario lo desea. Cuando me llevo el código en mi editor de código, lo primero, es que el código de la function CrearVentana() no lo entiendo y lo segundo, es que lo pruebo en el navegador y no funciona.
¿Alguien sabría decirme donde está el error, o por consiguiente, si le sobra código innecesario?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>OBJETO WINDOW - ventanas</title>

<script> 


    var ventana;

    function CrearVentana(){
        var opciones="left=100,top=100,";
        opciones=opciones +"width="+document.FORMULARIO[0].value+","; 
        opciones=opciones +"height="+document.FORMULARIO[1].value; 
        ventana = window.open(",",opciones); 
        ventana.document.write("Ventana nueva con el tamaño ");
    }

    function CerrarVentana(){

        if(ventana && !ventana.closed){

        ventana.close();

        window.close();
        }
    }

</script>
</head>


<body>

    <p align="center"><b> INTRODUCE EL ANCHO Y EL ALTO DE LA VENTANA:</b></p>

    <center>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tr>

            <td bgcolor="#FFFF96">
                <form name="FORMULARIO">
                    <p><b>ancho de la ventana:</b><input type="text" name="ancho" size="10"/></p>
                    <p><b>alto de la ventana:</b><input type="text" name="alto" size="10"/></p>
                    <input type="button" value="Crear Ventana" name="B1" onclick="CrearVentana()">
                    <input type="button" value="Cerrar Ventana" name="B2" onclick="CerrarVentana()">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cuando dices que el codigo no funciona , que quieres decir , que error te da , no hace nada ?

Comment: La verdad es que el código no está muy bien planteado, y como bien dices no funciona, pero no da error. Échale al apartado de NDM donde dice errores  `[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors) a ver si encuentras alguna solucion.

Comment: @EnricBorralloRodriguez No da error, sino que simplemente no funciona.